# Use Ant to build junit test with initializationError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit, build

This is failure trace from junit test report:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

This is my build.xml:

```
<project name="Ant-Test-JUnit" default="main">
<description>
        JUnit Test on MyMath
</description>

<property name="src.dir" location="src"/>
<property name="bin.dir" location="bin"/>

<!-- Variables used for JUnit testin -->
<property name="test.dir" location="src" />
<property name="test.report.dir" location="testreport" />

<path id="test.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${bin.dir}" />
    <pathelement location="../../../../plugins/org.junit_4.11.0.v201203080030/junit.jar" />     
    <pathelement location="../../../../plugins/org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar"/>
</path>

<!-- ================================= 
      target: main             
     ================================= -->
<target name="main" depends="compile, junit">
    <echo message="Junit Test :)"/>
</target>

<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
      target: compile                      
     - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${bin.dir}">
        <classpath refid="test.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
              target: clean, makedir                   
     - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${bin}"/>
    <delete dir="${test.report.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="makedir">
    <mkdir dir="${bin.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${test.report.dir}" />
</target>

<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
          target: junit                      
     - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<target name="junit" depends="compile">
    <junit printsummary="yes" fork="true" haltonfailure="yes">
        <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <batchtest todir="${test.report.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
              <include name="**/*UnitTest*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

I've added Junit_4.11 jar to Preference->Ant->Runtime->Global Entries
and package org.hamcrest.* to Preference->JUnit->Add Packages(but this doesn't fix the problem of NoClassDefFoundError:org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing)

If I run UnitTest*.java using JUnit plugin in eclipse directly, it works and shows all tests passed.

Could anyone help me figure out the solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. This is caused by wrong path location. I just changed the path element to the right location and solve it. Ant just needs correct path. Each time check if the location is right.

replace

```
<pathelement location="../../../../plugins/org.junit_4.11.0.v201203080030/junit.jar" />     
<pathelement location="../../../../plugins/org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar"/>
```

with

```
<pathelement location="/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030/junit.jar"/>
<pathelement location="/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar"/>
```